# Compactly supported weak solution : Help with proof

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Consider a nonlinear PDE for $p(x,y)$  defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$:

\begin{equation} N p(x,y)=0, \:\:\:\:\:\:\:Eq. (1)\end{equation}

where $N$ is a 2nd order nonlinear operator. The variable $p$ is like "density". The only BCs I have is that $p$ is zero at infinity.

Now a particular solution, $\hat{p}$, turns out to be independent of $y$, i.e,  $\hat{p}=\hat{p}(x)$. That is,

$N\hat{p}(x)=0$.

However, due to the physical motivation behind this problem, I want to find a solution with compact support in $y$. The reason is that I want the integral of $\hat{p}$ over all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be bounded.

**My Question:**

Let 
$q(x,y)=\hat{p}(x)\mathbb{I}_{\Omega}(y)$, where $\mathbb{I}_{\Omega}$ is the characteristic function of a well-chosen set $\Omega\in \mathbb{R}$. 
Can I claim that the $q(x,y)$ is also a weak solution of Eq. (1)?

I am not sure how to rigorously justify this construction. Is the theory of distributions applicable here ? Clearly $q(x,y)$ satisfies the equation except at set of measure 0, which is the boundary of $\Omega$.

Comment: Typically no, typically the thin "bad" set will appear in the distributional version of $Nq$, making it nonzero. If you think about it, that has to be the case, otherwise weak solutions would be bizarre: you could just arbitrarily decide to cut off a given weak solution wherever you please and get a new weak solution.

Comment: Also, just having compact support in the $y$ variable does not help you get integrability by itself.

Comment: @Ian since the variable $p$ is density, and the decay in $x$ results in bounded integral, if I am able to normalize the integral over finite domain in $y$...I would get what I need

Comment: That would do it in combination, sure.

Comment: @Ian regarding your original comment, does your argument also apply to measure valued solutions ?

Comment: It does not really matter, any reasonable "weak version" of a differential operator sees changes even on small sets.